# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ChartWrapper' of undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, google-visualization

I'm trying to integrate Google Charts with Wordpress, using Advanced Custom Fields input to populate the data. After just one iteration in the Javascript, [it crashes, despite proper data formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKXQE.jpg).

From other questions I gathered google.visualization must not be loading in time since it's undefined, but the authors of those questions didn't use setOnLoadCallback. I have, which should address that. What am I misunderstanding?

functions.php:

```
function create_chart(){  
    if( have_rows('chart') ){  
        wp_enqueue_script( 'google-charts', 'https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js' );  

        $chart_data = array();  
        while( have_rows('chart') )  
            array_push( $chart_data, the_row(true) );  

        wp_register_script( 'chart-generator', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/chart-generator.js' );  
        wp_enqueue_script( 'chart-generator', true );  
        wp_localize_script( 'chart-generator', 'chart_data', $chart_data);  
    }  
}  
add_action( 'wp_head', 'create_chart');
```

chart-generator.js

```
(function($){  
    google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});  
    for(i=0; i<chart_data.length; i++){  

        // Reencodes objects as arrays  
        next_chart = chart_data[i];  
        for(j=0; j<next_chart.entry.length; j++)  
            next_chart.entry[j] = Object.values( next_chart.entry[j] );  
        console.log(next_chart);  

        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(  
            drawPieChart(  
                next_chart.title,  
                next_chart.id,  
                next_chart.colors,  
                next_chart.entry));  
    }  
})(jQuery);  

function drawPieChart( title, id, colors, entries) {  
    // Appends to beginning of array  
    entries.unshift( ['title', 'quantity'] );  

    var wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({              
        chartType: 'PieChart',  
        dataTable: google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(entries),  
        options: {  
            'title': title,  
            pieHole: 0.4,  
        },  
        containerId: id  
    });  
    wrapper.draw();  
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="onechart" style="width:200px; height: 200px;"></div>  
<div id="twochart" style="width:200px; height: 200px;"></div>  
<div id="redchart" style="width:200px; height: 200px;"></div>  
<div id="vis_div" style="width:200px; height: 200px;"></div>  
<div id="burger" style="width:200px; height: 200px;"></div>
```

Comment: Not sure this makes sense...`google.charts.setOnLoadCallback ` would that not be `google.setOnLoadCallback`? Issue being calling charts before loaded...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you need to load the `'controls'` package,
when using `ChartWrapper` or `ControlWrapper`

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'controls']});
```

---

next, `setOnLoadCallback` takes a reference to a `function`,
not the result of a `function()`

it should be --> `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawPieChart);`

if you need to pass arguments to the callback,
add an anonymous function, or something similar in between...

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
  drawPieChart(  
    next_chart.title,  
    next_chart.id,  
    next_chart.colors,  
    next_chart.entry
  );
});
```

---

also, the callback only needs to be used once,
after it fires the first time, you can drawn as many charts as needed

recommend restructure as follows...

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'controls']});  
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
  for(i=0; i<chart_data.length; i++){  
      // Reencodes objects as arrays  
      next_chart = chart_data[i];  
      for(j=0; j<next_chart.entry.length; j++)  
          next_chart.entry[j] = Object.values( next_chart.entry[j] );  
      console.log(next_chart);  

          drawPieChart(  
              next_chart.title,  
              next_chart.id,  
              next_chart.colors,  
              next_chart.entry);  
  }  
});
```